# Getting a TS2339 error with optional property declaration when destructuring

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Being new to typescript i am having trouble figuring this out

When i try to destructure an optional property (which is an object) from redux store i get the TS2339 error

This is the typescript declaration

```
export interface CoreState {
  // readonly confirm?: CoreConfirm;
  readonly confirm?: {
    title: string
    readonly content: string | React.ReactNode
    readonly confirmText: string
    readonly declineText: string
    onConfirm(): void
    onDecline(): void
    onClose(): void
  };
}
```

I then try and destructure it like so

```
const {
      closeConfirm,
      confirmOpen,
      confirm: {
        title,
        content,
        onConfirm,
        onDecline,
        onClose,
        ...options
      },
    } = this.props;
```

But i get this error on all them sub properties on confirm (like title, content etc)

```
Property 'title' does not exist on type '{ title: string; readonly content: ReactNode; readonly confirmText: string; readonly declineText: string; onConfirm(): void; onDecline(): void; onClose(): void; } | undefined'.
```

However if i just access the sub property directly i can 'supress' the error messages

```
const title = this.props.confirm && this.props.confirm.title;
```

However i would really like to be able to destructure the props, how can i accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i ended up doing it - still feels wonky but the typescript errors are gone

```
const {
  closeConfirm,
  confirmOpen,
} = this.props;

const {
  title,
  content,
  onConfirm,
  onDecline,
  onClose = () => {},
  ...options
} = this.props.confirm!;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure `confirm` exists in props then you can tell the typechecker this info using `!` operator

`const title = this.props.confirm!.title;`

```
const {
      closeConfirm,
      confirmOpen,
      confirm
    } = this.props;
if (confirm){
const {
        title,
        content,
        onConfirm,
        onDecline,
        onClose,
        ...options
      } = confirm
}
```

Comment: confirm is optional so it does not always exist and that is what is my issue, also its the destructuring i am having problems with, not the direct access from this.props.confirm

Comment: @Hammersholt I've updated the answer on how to destruct

Comment: Cool the if statement supresses the error, but it feels wonky.

Isn't there a way to do it in one go like i tried?

Comment: And the issue with this if approach is scoping, i dont have access to the destructed variables